# Azure DevOps user migration

Tags: azure-devops, user-management

After a couple companies merge, we had to build up an AZ DevOps solution from scratch for the new business entity. Unfortunately, at that time we added some users from various companies under their original email addresses (reason: reuse of their VS subscriptions).

Now we need to migrate these users in Azure DevOps from their old **bill.smith@oldcompany.com** to their new **bill.smith@newcompany.com** without losing their work and settings. Afterwards the users should be able to log in with their new emails and see everything as if they would log in with their old addresses.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a support case and they can help you out. You get a excel file to map users between the domains and they can map them over in one go.

Answer (score 1):

*jessehouwing* is right, if you want to migrate data to new Azure DevOps users, you need submit a support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/).

But there are something you need pay attention and get ready first:

- **Do not add them (bill.smith@newcompany.com)  to Azure DevOps Service or let them logon to Azure DevOps Service.** At this point
  Azure DevOps Service support needs to migrate/transfer the users.
- Provide a mapping list of users (old user > new user) to Azure DevOps
  Service Support.

---

Azure DevOps Service will transfer identities to the new users. This should add the new account to Azure DevOps Service, assign work items to the new account, assign the Azure DevOps Service license to the new account , and remove the old account from Azure DevOps Service.

Comment: @jessehowing was actually first to react and I reacted upon his answer. But thx u 2